# php mysql retrieving single value from database

Tags: php, mysql, database, updating

Hey guys this is a really noob question but for some reason I can't seem to get a single value from a database.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column FROM teacher WHERE id = :id")
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$oldValue = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

I do filter the variables before in the code because I got them in this file as post data, here's the code for that part:

```
$column = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "column", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "id", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "value", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

In this same file updating the database works so its probably not a problem with connecting to the database. Please help! Thanks

Full error from $stmt:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column FROM teacher WHERE id = ?' at line 1' in /var/www/duties/testTableDataUpload.php:25Stack trace:#0 /var/www/duties/testTableDataUpload.php(25): PDO->prepare('SELECT column F...')#1 {main}  thrown in /var/www/duties/testTableDataUpload.php on line 25

Comment: What output are you seeing? Is your $pdo object valid? Why don't you check $stmt to see if it comes back false, and if so, check last error?

Comment: I hope your query is not literally "SELECT column FROM teacher WHERE id = :id" and you are actually putting a column name in

Comment: the column variable just holds the name of one of the columns in the database, for checking the errors im not actually sure how because im using ajax to run this file seperate from my main file and it doesnt look like it works in the same way running a normal file does

Comment: what results are you getting back?  add print_r($stmt->errorInfo()); after your execute.

Comment: what i do to check errors of ajax call to db is in my success parameter i say alert(result).  then the result will be printed to window, and the result should equal whatever you echo in your php page call to db.  in this case "print_r($stmt->errorInfo())"

Comment: I added the print_r($stmt->errorInfo()) but its not giving me a message or anything       edit: am adding suggested code

Comment: im going to add an answer, i know its not correct, but i dont know how else to show code. see below.

Comment: would I just put the alert(result) in the success parameter inside my main file? if thats the case then how do i get the result data from my seperate file to my main file

Comment: Did you confirm that the value is actually IN the database to start with?

Comment: yes. in the success parameter, result becomes whatever you print on the php db page.  so if you did echo $oldValue on the php db php.  alert(result) would show whatever $oldValue is.

Comment: yeah the alert is working now but i dont know how to copy the alert text. It says something about a pdo exception and stack trace on the same line as the prepare statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not an answer, just trying to post code to OP.

jquery:

```
var data="id="+id;
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data: data,
            url:"somePHPdbPage.php",
            success: function(result){
            $('#blah').html(result);
            }
    });
```

Then somewhere on your main page do:

```
 <div id='blah'></div>
```

what this will do is add the result to the div blah. and you should plainly see it on your main page. then c/p all you want.  Have to head out for a bit.  will check back in.

and on your php page:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column FROM teacher WHERE id = :id")
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
```

Comment: ok thanks, it looks the alert thing works. I have some syntax error , gonna try fixing it

Comment: ok so I fixed it and it the error says I have some kind of stack trace error on the same line as the prepare statement. it also says something about a pdo exception. Is there a way to copy/paste error reports? in an alert box ofc

Comment: that says your select statment is bad. is column a real column? or are you changing it to post here?

Comment: column should be a real column, its just set to one of the names of the columns from the database

Comment: should it be $column instead of just column? be back soon.

Comment: thank you so much that worked either your a genius or im a dumbass

Answer (score 1):

`column` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and must be escaped using '`'. You are also missing a semicolon at the end of the line. Try the following:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `column` FROM teacher WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$oldValue = $stmt->fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem be with your data but if there be duplicated data you can use one of the belows:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT distinct column FROM teacher WHERE id = :id")
```

or

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT column FROM teacher WHERE id = :id limit 1")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column in the teach tabled named 'first_name' you should be able to do the following

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT first_name FROM teacher WHERE id = :id ORDER BY id DESC limit 1")
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO:FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $row['first_name']; //Will print out the first name (if that is a column in your table of course)
```